# Making a custom action dll using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, wix, wix3.5

I am working on an installer that requires some customactiondll ihave understod that i need to have  a cpp file that could be converted to .dll .

I have been reading the posts on the internet mst of them relates to VS 6.0 , i am using this VS 2010 Ultimate, i am running a x64 machine i have written the .cpp file , please help me step by step increation of a .dll in VS 2010 ultimate i have got Votive installed as well.

I am not using any of the VS's to create my installers however i am using Notepad ++ for the XML coding and command line to compile my code .

Please help me step by step so that i can successfully create a .dll

For the time being one can consider [Wix Tutorial What's not in book](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/events-and-actions/whats-not-in-the-book)!

I am working with CASAMPLE.dll that can be downloaded [here](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/events-and-actions/whats-not-in-the-book)!

Please help
Thanks

Comment: Is your problem about creation of dll in general?

Comment: well i have a sampleca downloaded from the link mentioned above however i am simply building the code by making a custom action project the build does not seems to work

Comment: Create a custom action project via Votive.Build it - you will get dll-file named like ProjectName.CA.dll. Insert the information about this library to the Binary Table of msi and use it.

Answer (score 0):

In VS2010 create a C++ Custom Action Project and create what functions you need and upon building this it will create your DLL file in the bin folder..:)